# Create Token in stripe using existing card info and customer id

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.js

I am using stripe.js with php and I am having issue in creating token for existing/saved cards and for new card everything works fine. Is there any function to generate token based on cardId and customerId

Answer (score 2):

It is neither necessary nor possible to create a new token from an existing Customer or Card object. Once a card has been stored on a Customer object, you can complete a charge using only your secret key and the Customer ID. From [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later):

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

// Token is created using Stripe.js or Checkout!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create a Customer:
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "email" => "paying.user@example.com",
  "source" => $token,
));

// Charge the Customer instead of the card:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer->id
));

// YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later.

// YOUR CODE (LATER): When it's time to charge the customer again, retrieve the customer ID.
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1500, // $15.00 this time
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer_id
));
```

If you have any other questions about how to implement a particular payment flow on Stripe I'd recommend getting in touch with [Stripe support](https://support.stripe.com/email/login).